# Amasty Extension - Sales Reps and Dealers - Custom Attributes

Tags: attributes, extensions, customer

Hey guys I'm using this extension:
https://amasty.com/sales-reps-and-dealers.html

It works beautifully but I want to make some adjustments.  Essentially it creates sales reps/dealers that can have their own customers under them.
Here is a visual diagram:

```
                               Our Awesome Company
                              /        |         \
                           Dealer1     |        Dealer2
                             /         |           \
                        Customers1    Customers2    Customers3
```

Our company can see all customers from groups 1,2,3.

Dealer1 can only see Customers1 and Dealer2 can only see Customers3

From what I know about SQL the customers must be linked in some way to their dealers, how would I go about checking who their dealers are?  I'm hoping I can find their relation in a SQL search and eventually figure out a way to call getData('something') to see a customer's dealer.

Let me know if I can clarify my question in anyway!  I tried to explain everything in a way where people without this extension could help out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at table `am_perm`

perm_id | uid | cid

Where:

```
'uid' = magento admin id 
'cid' = customer id.
```

To look up dealer by order id

```
Mage::getModel('amperm/perm')->getUserByOrder($orderId);

Mage::helper('amperm')->getCurrentSalesPersonId()
```

To lookup a dealer by customer Id

```
$perm = Mage::getModel('amperm/perm')->load($customerId, 'cid');

if($perm->getId()){
   $adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($perm->getUid());
   echo $adminUser->getFirstname();
}
```

Comment: If I'm logged in as a customer/user is there no way to see my dealer? Or can I only access it by orderId? If possible I want to see the dealer in the customer's dash board! Thanks for answering btw!

Comment: omg you're awesome. I'm checking the database through my cPanel. Is there a way from a customers dashboard to see who their dealer or 'uid' is? Their cid from what I can tell is just the regular customersId.

Comment: @CodingMageSheen .. take a look at my update

Comment: perfect thank you I've selected your answer!